# Tortoise SVN export settings

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

can i somehow export settings from Tortoise SVN(i mean Tortoise SVN client settings, not subversion).
I must install Tortoise SVN for whole develop team and don`t want to set up client many times.
I tried to search on Google but found nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The settings are in the registry under `HKCU\Software\TortoiseSVN`, e.g., cache type, include and exclude folders, preferred diff tool, etc.

You can export that branch of the registry to a `.reg` file (**right-click/Export** in RegEdit), strip out the settings you don't want to change, and then load that on the workstations using a batch file, login script or similar.

Put this in the batch file:

```
regedit /s MyPathTo/MyExportFile.reg
```

The `/s` parameter will suppress the confirmation dialog before the .reg file is merged into the registry.